# Alias not working on Ubuntu 16.04 for Python3

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias

I followed these directions:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/make-default-python-symbolic-link-to-link-to-python3

The site gave instructions on how to make an alias for python 3. It's pretty simple, yet i can't see how it isn't working for me.

This is what I have done:

```bash
admin@Jerry:~$ cat ~/.bash_aliases
alias py=python3
admin@Jerry:~$ source ~/.bash_aliases
admin@Jerry:~$ py
py: command not found

admin@Jerry:~$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias py='python3'
alias python='python3'
alias python3='py'

admin@Jerry:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing.

**EDIT 1:** 'alias' and 'which python3' command is added

Comment: What is the output of the following commands: `alias` and `which python3` ?

Comment: @ChristianTernus Code is added. I see that i have an alias for python='python3'. Does that do anything? I added it before, but deleted it and replaced the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the `py='python3'` alias circularly. To fix this, unset the `python3='py'` alias by doing:

`unalias python3`